# Japanese term for morning office mantra ritual

Tags: word-requests

This is a follow-on question to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/476431/107198) which was asked on the English Language stack.

The phenomenon in question is the typical Japanese workplace ritual where team members will begin the day with some type of communal mantra or recitation of the workplace values, etc.

The question is whether there is a specific single word or term in Japanese for this ritual and, if so, what is it called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of 朝礼{ちょうれい} (chourei/chōrei). Here's some blog posts about the practice:

- https://newsnmylife.wordpress.com/tag/chourei/
- http://ameliemarieintokyo.com/en/the-morning-greetings-in-japanese-work-place/
- https://clivebgordon.com/2016/04/25/workplace-culture-shock/

Mantra/company values are called 社訓{しゃくん} or 社是{しゃぜ}.

The part of 朝礼 that involves the process of chanting it I don't think quite has a formalized name, but the most common seems to be 社訓を唱和{しょうわ}する. I've also seen the following:

- 社訓を朝礼で唱える{となえる}
- 社是を唱える
- 社訓を読み上げる
- 経営理念唱和

Comment: 朝礼 includes just regular meeting activities, though - like members reporting their progress on projects, giving updates, quick presentations, etc.  I mean specifically the ritualized elements that might be part of 朝礼 - everyone reciting team values together and so on.  This is something that is the same every single day - not individually reported details relevant to the working day today.

Comment: @J... I updated my answer to be more specific.